# How can I prevent re-rendering of my component in React Navigation version 5.x using createStackNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

In my React Native app I use a StackNavigator, more or less as follows:

```
// React navigation
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// Create stack navigator
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator detachInactiveScreens={false} screenOptions={{ header: () => null }}>
                <Stack.Screen name="master" component={MasterView} />
                <Stack.Screen name="detail" component={DetailView} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

While the user uses the app he/she switches back and forth between MasterView and DetailView. The DetailView is reinstantiated
anytime the user navigates to it. However I need to prevent the DetailView to be reinstantiated upon navigation. I was hoping
to use the property detachInactiveScreens to accomplish this behavior as described here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#detachinactivescreens

I also included the invocation of enableScreens as follows in App.tsx

```
// Import react-native-screens
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';
enableScreens();
```

However I still see my DetailView being reinstantiated anytime the user navigates to it. Am I following the wrong approach? Is there
an alternative way to accomplish this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's how stack navigator works. If you don't want the screen to be unmounted when you go back, then you need another navigator or build a custom one if they don't match your expected behavior.